# String splitting before character

Tags: string, go, split, substring, slice

I'm new to go and have been using split to my advantage. Recently I came across a problem I wanted to split something, and keep the splitting char in my second slice rather than removing it, or leaving it in the first slice as with SplitAfter.

For example the following code:

```
strings.Split("email@email.com", "@")
```

returned: `["email", "email.com"]`

```
strings.SplitAfter("email@email.com", "@")
```

returned: `["email@", "email.com"]`

What's the best way to get `["email", "@email.com"]`?

Comment: The simplest way would be to just "prepend" the separator to each but the first item in the returned slice. https://play.golang.com/p/sA33rVeJjRt

Comment: What he did was basically what I did, but he gave you a nice function to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strings.Index](https://godoc.org/strings#Index) to find the `@` and slice to get the two parts:

```
var part1, part2 string
if i := strings.Index(s, "@"); i >= 0 {
    part1, part2 = s[:i], s[i:]
} else {
    // handle case with no @
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VwG4LXctv87).

Comment: Using your suggestion here's a more complete implementation: https://play.golang.org/p/P4rZvBAuSih

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you?

```
s := strings.Split("email@email.com", "@")
address, domain := s[0], "@"+s[1]
fmt.Println(address, domain)
// email @email.com
```

Then combing and creating a string

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer
buffer.WriteString(address)
buffer.WriteString(domain)
result := buffer.String()
fmt.Println(result)
// email@email.com
```

Comment: The code in this answer will panic if the string does not contain an @.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bufio.Scanner`:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "strings"
)

func email(data []byte, eof bool) (int, []byte, error) {
   for i, b := range data {
      if b == '@' {
         if i > 0 {
            return i, data[:i], nil
         }
         return len(data), data, nil
      }
   }
   return 0, nil, nil
}

func main() {
   s := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader("email@email.com"))
   s.Split(email)
   for s.Scan() {
      println(s.Text())
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/bufio#Scanner.Split